# ¿Cómo hacer la página "not found" en node js express?

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Estoy trabajando con `node.js` y `express`. Ahora lo que estoy buscando es hacer la página *"not found 404"* para mi sitio web;

esta es mi "app.js":

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , user = require('./routes/user')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path');

var app = express();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
    app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/users', user.list);
app.get('/notfound', routes.index);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Estuve intentando con `app.get('/notfound', routes.index);` pero me da un error de `Cannot GET /notfound`

También intente con: `app.get('/*', routes.index);` pero me da un error de `Cannot GET /*`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La idea es redirigir cuando se obtenga una respuesta `404`, algo como esto:

```
app.use(app.router);

// $ curl http://localhost:3000/notfound
// $ curl http://localhost:3000/notfound -H "Accept: application/json"
// $ curl http://localhost:3000/notfound -H "Accept: text/plain"

app.use(function(req, res, next){
  res.status(404);

  // Respuesta html
  if (req.accepts('html')) {
    res.render('404', { url: req.url });
    return;
  }

  // Respuesta json
  if (req.accepts('json')) {
    res.send({ error: 'Not found' });
    return;
  }

  // Texto plano
  res.type('txt').send('Not found');
});
```

Puedes ver [el ejemplo completo aquí](https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/master/examples/error-pages/index.js).

Comment: muchas gracias, me sirvió mucho tu ayuda

Answer (score 2):

Puedes renderizar en una sola línea tu propio archivo .html de la siguiente forma ;)

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
        res.status(404).render('404.html');
});
```